# Generating ERC20 Token on main network

Tags: solidity, remix

I have done up the scripts on Remix and managed to generate Tokens successfully on Ropsten Network.

However, when using the exact contract script on actual main network, the status remain as "pending contract creation" .

Anyone can give a guidance here? Appreciate it!

Comment: Did you use enough gas?

Comment: Should be. Remix recommended GAS & GWEI of approximately USD 4.00 and I have adjusted the GWEI much higher. 

and on ETH Gas station, based on the GAS value, the time should be about 1 minute. 

However waited for almost 8 hours. (this repeated several attempts)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have set a high enough gas price. Check the [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/) for an estimate how how long a given transaction will take at a given gas price.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot ! at first i was suspecting it. So i up the ETH in metamask, on top of that, adjusted higher GWEI than the recommended one (before the contract is being compiled and processed, Solidity generates a window suggesting GAS & GWEI.

Do you know if i have to change any of the script in order to run in Main net?

or it is purely due to reason of insufficient balance of Ethereum in Metamask ?

Comment: No, from a tech point of view, you shouldn't have to change anything in your solidity code, it should work identically on a Test Net as it does on the Main Net. But you may need to pay a higher gas price on the Main Net for economic reasons.

Comment: Thanks ! @AnAllergyToAnalogy . The remix recommended GAS volume, and Gwei at 4. I have actually upped higher to 40 (ten times more). You recommending even higher ?